# App store connect reject build because missing NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I use Xcode 10.3 to distribute my app. Then App store connect always reject the build. And I got an email said "The app's info.plist file should contain a NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data." I added the key "Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description". But got the rejection yet. There was "Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description” already and it was ok since today. So how to resolve this?

Comment: what did you write in your description in info.plist? description should be self explanatory like why your app needs bluetooth access.

Comment: As @DeepakVerma told, you only required to mention about what is the purpose for using bluetooth in your application. Just mention that against 'NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription' in info.plist. Then Appstore connect will not reject your app due to this reason.

Comment: @MehulThakkar ya, it works.

Comment: look at this for the root cause details and the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58008066/1844851

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll need to add the purpose : Why your app requires Bluetooth to be enabled. Something like this :

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>App uses Bluetooth to find, connect and communicate with nearby devices. Please grant access.</string>
```

Comment: it works ok? I added this to info.plist. the xcode can not recognize it. and I upload to app store connect, it always show as processing~~~

Comment: works now, automaticlly~~~ but about an hour before this, the state comes to be "Importing this build failed".

Comment: Well, my app's target is iOS 14 and I had `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` there from the beginning, yet the app got rejected requiring the deprecated `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`

Answer (score 6):

Just putting a purpose without knowing what is using it would not be the best way to handle this.

I had this exact same issue. When I did a grep search I found that there is some reference to CoreBluetooth.framework inside my project.pbxproj

I removed the reference and building the app went fine. Uploaded to Apple and it got through so this worked for me.

To search use the following command

```
grep -r -a CoreBluetooth.framework ProjectFolder
```

Comment: this is correct answer, if there is no usage of bluetooth then why adding keys in info.plist, just remove CoreBluetooth.framework and resubmit

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is right but not full. You really need to add this key into your .plist file. But `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` added in iOS 13+. If you target iOS below 13, you also need to add `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` in addition to first key.

Answer (score 1):

Open your info.plist as source code and add below line

```
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs bluetooth access to connect via bluetooth.</string>

//remember need bluetooth access to connect via bluetooth is just an arbitrary message. You should change it according to your needs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps: click on info.plist > open as source code > add the follow

NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription
   We use Bluetooth to connect to the MantisX hardware device.