# The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key while the key is in the plist file

Tags: ios, react-native, info.plist

First of all, I would like to state that I already looked at [Stack Overflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991494/app-store-connect-reject-build-because-missing-nsbluetoothalwaysusagedescription) and adding either the one mentioned by either iCoder & Deepak didn't solve the problem for me.

I'm using React-Native to develop my apps including this [React-Native-Permissions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions) package I found. Their documentation states that I should add all the permission their package enables e.g. Location, Camera and all the others mentioned there. After I did this I was able to upload my application to the store and submit it for review.

Today I got to the office and I saw there was some feedback from Apple available. So after I completed the feedback I wanted to re-upload to the store again (increasing the build number as I'm supposed to do).

And now I keep getting the message in the title mentioned above while I have it present in my info.plist like such

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Our app does not request this permission or utilize this functionality but it is included in our info.plist since our app utilizes the react-native-permissions library, which references this permission in its code.</string>
```

EDIT:

I hope to clarify things below in order to find an answer to the problem I'm facing. The error given in the title occurs directly after uploading to the store (So I'm guessing the actual error is picked up the automatic checks done by the system).

The answer below won't help me to fix the problem since the more descriptive string wont be checked by the automatic system check. And I've successfully used this string for other elements in the info.plist. Next to this I found evidence that people successfully submit their app to the app store using this tactic. As shown by the comment of Gradner following this link [React Native Permission issue 266](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions/issues/266)

Comment: Description string should be self explanatory. Try changing your description string to something which specifies why your application needs this permission.Like "our app needs access to your bluetooth to connect via bluetooth"

Comment: Well that's the thing. Since I'm using the ReactNativePermissions package to handle permissions there is code in the project that requires me to add the key to the info.plist. However, I never will ask the user for this permission. To maybe clarify things I got this error from the automatic checks after uploading, not as feedback provided by the review process

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Comment: @MikeSli - Do you also have a `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` key + description?

Comment: Yes that key is also present using the same description as I mentioned in my question

Comment: According to Apple's docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsbluetoothalwaysusagedescription) the `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` key is only for iOS 13+ ... it's possible the auto-processing system is not interpreting it correctly. Try removing that key and see what happens.

Comment: Well I'll give that a shot but I don't think it will resolve the problem since I only added it because the system told me to do so. I'll let you know the results

Comment: @DonMag I've just tried uploading the app again without the NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key and it fails again after uploading thanks to the automatic process

Comment: @MikeSli - I don't use React-Native, but taking a quick look at that "Permissions" package and the Issues / Discussions, I'd suggest forking the repo and removing the ones you don't use (such as Bluetooth). Then you won't have to fuss with it.

Comment: @MikeSli I have a same problem. I used to upload the app without any problem until yesterday, and today I tried to upload new build with new build number.
And it is being continuously rejected. so have you figured it out?

Comment: @MikeSli - i also had the same issue while uploading the build, so first i added the `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` from the drop down in `info.plist` then also they rejected binary with same reasons so what i did is opened the info.plist as source code and replaced `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` with `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` key and it finally got accepted.

Comment: @zanytycoon Well I just got into the office again and I'll start trying with the solution provided by Sumeet.Jain. Otherwise I'll go and fork the repository of react-native-permissions and remove the permissions I don't need

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Someone posted an answer that helped me, but then deleted it! To paraphrase the answer:

Adding the privacy keys to the plist without knowing what is triggering the error from Apple is not the best way to solve this.

In my case, when I did a grep search I found that there is some reference to `CoreBluetooth.framework` inside my `project.pbxproj`. I removed the reference and the build and TestFlight upload succeeded!

To search use the following command:

```
grep -r -a CoreBluetooth.framework ProjectFolder
```

Comment: I do agree this solution would be the best taking the user into consideration. Although for the time being this isn't the solution I've used. I would consider doing this when I'll launch the first update with bugfixes for my app. Or I might consider to fork the repo and remove the permissions I don't use. Currently I think the answer above is the best so that is why I'll mark it as the correct one

Comment: I ran `grep -r -a CoreBluetooth.framework ./*` and nothing were found. Would this warning only get triggered by using CoreBluetooth.framework only or are there other phrases that I must look for?

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem? Why does it complain about the permission if it's in the info.plist?

Comment: The grep command above yielded a wall of text that was hard to decipher, but this command worked better for me to figure out which binary had the references: `grep -r -H --binary CoreBluetooth.framework ./*`

Answer (score 67):

#### If you are not using Bluetooth,

just add this to your Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Our app does not request this permission or utilize this functionality but it is included in our info.plist since our app utilizes the react-native-permissions library, which references this permission in its code.</string>
```

Apple deprecated NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription property in favor of NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription.

See details here:
[link to Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsbluetoothalwaysusagedescription)

#### If you are using bluetooth,

just add this to your Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Our app uses bluetooth to find, connect and transfer data between different devices</string>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't the answer.

Comment: Dunno but thanks to this I got a rare Badge: Populist

Answer (score 6):

I got the root cause

We have below two default options in plist to enter the bluetooth usage.

1.Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description
2.Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description

But Xcode save this option in the source code like the below

1.NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription instead of Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description

2.Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description instead of Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description

So now the point is
NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription is deprecated and its expecting the key "NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription"

> Here is the solution, open the plist file as source code in Xcode and
>   copy-paste the below key-value pair
>
> Key: NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription Value: This application
>   requires bluetooth in order to bla bla bla.

Comment: Well that is the thing I did have to include both of them in the info.plist file to work. Although uploading it for the first time with both of them present wouldn't work. It might be a simple typo but in these cases I always copy the values in order to make sure it is correct

Answer (score 4):

I can't figure out why the first time it wasn't working but when I got into the office today I saw the comment posted by Sumeet.Jain that suggested I should replace the

> NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with the NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key

This would actually result in an error that would say missing NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription as we might expect it to. So then I re-added the NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription to my info.plist and now I was finally able to upload my app to the store. Thanks for everyone that helped me.

p.s. The only thing I can think of I did differently compared to yesterday is that I now added the key using Xcode instead of just editing the info.plist file in my editor I use for react-native. Hopefully this helps others as it helped me

Answer (score 2):

Well, I fixed this issues.

if your app is using bluetooth so you must add this into info.plist.

NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription

Our app uses bluetooth to ...do something...

if your app doesn't need bluetooth but it's prompted with unexpectedly.

then:

open Xcode :
go to remove CoreBluetooth.framework:

1. -> yourproject -> frameworks -> CoreBluetooth.framework
2. -> yourproject -> Build Phases -> Type Search to find "Bluetooth" (remove all related "Bluetooth")

It's works for me!
Hope will help you.

Answer (score 1):

For deployment targets earlier than iOS 13, add both NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription and NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription to your app’s Information Property List file

String depends upon you if you are using Bluetooth or not.

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Our app does not request this permission or utilize this functionality but it is included in our info.plist since our app utilizes some library, which references this permission in its code.</string>
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Our app does not request this permission or utilize this functionality but it is included in our info.plist since our app utilizes some library, which references this permission in its code.</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully remove the Bluetooth permission alert when the app opens. In my case the problem was with the library "react-native-connectivity-status". I downgraded the library from version "1.5.2" to "1.5.1".

Here are the steps:

Change

```
"react-native-connectivity-status": "^1.5.1",
```

To

```
"react-native-connectivity-status": "1.5.1",
```

Then ran following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm package-lock.json
npm i
cd ios/
rm -rf Pods/
pod install
```