# React Native Remove Bluetooth Permission Alert for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am not requesting bluetooth permission in my app code but it's asking for permission alert in iOS when the app loads.

I couldn't find any reference in my code and I followed all the solutions suggested in this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992330/the-apps-info-plist-file-should-contain-a-nsbluetoothalwaysusagedescription-key) but it didn't work

I also added the below purpose string into info.plist for NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription but apple rejected the app.

"Our app does not request this permission or utilize this functionality but it is included in our info.plist since our app utilizes the react-native-permissions library, which references this permission in its code."

If anyone had same issue and was able to resolve this, please help. Thanks

Here is the pod file:

```html
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
  versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.33.1'
  versions['DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
  versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.1'
  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
  versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
  versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.0'

  pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'

  # List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
  # to avoid them being linked in Release builds
  pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['DoubleConversion'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
end

# Post Install processing for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'YogaKit'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'Urent' do

  # React Native
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

  # Pods for Urent
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'react-native-geolocation', path: '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'


  pod 'Firebase', '~> 6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.24.0'

  pod 'GoogleMaps', '3.5.0'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', '2.1.0'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '6.6.0'
  pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '6.5.0'


  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path # <~~ if you need GoogleMaps support on iOS


  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  target 'UrentTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  add_flipper_pods!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
        end
      end
      if target.name == "React"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'Urent-tvOS' do
  # Pods for Urent-tvOS

  target 'Urent-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to check the modules you are using. Common culprits are advertising frameworks and media playback frameworks.

Comment: @Paulw11, that's the issue, how would I know which module is using the bluetooth? I tried to search into node_modules and cocapods but didn't find anything.

Comment: You can either examine the source for those modules or remove likely candidates one at a time

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks but removing libraries and check is time consuming. I can do this only if there is no. other quick way to resolve this.

Comment: I suggest you start by looking at likely culprits; do you have any advertising frameworks? AV/media frameworks? Any Facebook frameworks? Without more information I can't tell you anything else.  Have you just linked to the Bluetooth framework in error?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't included the Bluetooth permission in your pod file.

Comment: I have used Facebook library but it's since beginning and before the app was fine and it wasn't asking for Bluetooth permission. For some reason I had to update some libraries and install pod but I didn't link because it is auto-linked. I published the app in TestFlight but it didn't go through then I just added purpose string for bluetooth in order to resolve the app on TestFlight. I think Bluetooth permission issue  occurred when I updated different library. I am not sure but I guess I updated "react-native-gesture-handler", "react-native-reanimated" and "react-native-svg" along with others.

Comment: Perhaps add your pod file to your question?

Comment: I added the pod file.

Comment: You said that you were using react-native-permissions, but you haven't inckuded any permissions modules in your pod file https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions?activeTab=readme

Comment: No, I never used react-native-permissions module.

Comment: Ok. You said that you did in your question; in your reply to Apple

Comment: I added the purpose string for "NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription" that our app doesn't require bluetooth permission..., but apple rejected and I replied that it's suggested by people whose app is accepted by giving such kind of purpose string but they replied and suggested me to follow the apple guideline which is general.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, I was able to resolve the issue and successfully removed the Bluetooth permission alert. In my case the problem was with the library "react-native-connectivity-status". I downgraded the library from version "1.5.2" to "1.5.1".
Here are the steps:

Change

```
"react-native-connectivity-status": "^1.5.1",
```

To

```
"react-native-connectivity-status": "1.5.1",
```

Then ran following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm package-lock.json
npm i
cd ios/
rm -rf Pods/
pod install
```